# Using mathematical induction show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\cdot2^i = n\cdot2^{n+1}+2$ for all $n\ge0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\cdot2^i = n\cdot2^{n+1}+2$ for all $n\ge0$

I start by showing that the property is true for n= 0

$1=2^1=2$} and $0\cdot2^{1} +2 = 2$

Then: show that for all integers $k\ge0$, if the property is true for n+1 =k, then it is true for n+1 = k+1.

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i\cdot2^i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} i\cdot2^i +(k+1)\cdot2^{k+1} $

$ = (k\cdot2^{k+2} +2) + (k+1)\cdot2^{k+1}$

$ = (k\cdot2^{k+2}+2) + 2k^{k+1}+ 2^{k+1} $

$ = (2k^{k+2} + 2k^{k+1} + 2^{k+1} +2$

Is this how you do it?

Comment: The statement is false for $n=0$. Please, fix it.

Comment: You should use \cdot for multiplication instead of \bullet

Comment: Why is it false though?

Comment: For $n=0$ you have $2$ on the left hand side and $0$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh, I had made an error in the question. My mistake, thank you for bringing it to my attention

Comment: For $n=1$ the left hand side is $1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2=10$ and the right hand side is $1\cdot2^{2}+2=6$. Still broken.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but the identity you're proving is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\,2^i=n\,2^{n+2}+2$$ for all $n \geq 0$.

So I'll just bug-fix your post:

> I start by showing that the property is true for $n=0$:
>
> The left-hand side is $1 \times 2^1=2$ and the right-hand side is $0\cdot 2^{2} +2 = 2$.  So the identity holds for $n=0$.
>
> Then: we show that for all integers $k\ge 1$, if the property is true for
>   $n=k-1$, then it is true for $n=k$.
>   We have:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i\,2^i &= \sum_{i=1}^{k} i\,2^i+(k+1)\,2^{k+1} \\
>  &= \big((k-1)\,2^{k+1} +2\big) + (k+1)\,2^{k+1} & \text{by the inductive hypothesis} \\
>  &= k\,2^{k+1}-2^{k+1}+2 + k\,2^{k+1}+ 2^{k+1} \\
>  &= k\,2^{k+2}+2.
> \end{align*}
>   Therefore by induction, the identity holds for all $n \geq 0$.